# Redirecting stderr to pipe from cron

Tags: linux, redirect, logging, cron, pipe

I'm trying to pipe stderr to logger with this code:

```
/usr/local/bin/Script.py >/dev/null 2>(/usr/bin/logger -t MyScript -p syslog.err)
```

This runs fine when run from a bash commandline but has no output in syslog when run from cron. This is my (root) crontab:

```
0-59/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/Script.py >/dev/null 2>(/usr/bin/logger -t MyScript -p syslog.err)
```

Can anybody help and tell me What is going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`>/dev/null` is redirecting both stdout/stderr to /dev/null before the `2>` redirection can pick it up.

Instead, redirect stdout to /dev/null explicitly:

```
/usr/local/bin/Script.py 1>/dev/null 2>(/usr/bin/logger -t MyScript -p syslog.err)
```